# onerror Event didn`t work

Tags: javascript, events, web, web-deployment, onerror

I try create code which replace src image on another. I want to use function invalidUrl():

```
function invalidUrl() {
    paint.src = randomvariable;
}
```

but this function isn`t running :<

```
var paint = '<img src="' + url + '"class="heightImg" onerror="invalidUrl()"/>' + '</br></br>' + description;
```

How to change src images if current picture doesn`t exist?

Comment: `paint.src` you cannot do this . because paint is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paint.src // undefined
```

this is because paint is of "string" type and strings have no "src" property.

You can use vanilla JavaScript to build your img element:

```
var paintedElement = document.createElement("img");
paintedElement.src = url;
paintedElement.class = "heightImg";
paintedElement.onerror = function invalidUrl() { 
     paint.src = randomvariable;
};
paintedElement.innerHTML = "</br></br>" + description;
// append where you need to append paintedElement
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're willing to use jQuery, you can create an element:

```
var paintelement=$('<img src="' + url + '"class="heightImg"/>' + '</br></br>' + description);
paintelement.attr('src','wherever');
paintelement.appendTo('#somewhere');
paintelement.on('error',function(){paint.src = randomvariable;});
```